# Toggle visibility of custom command of Dx-Diagram

Tags: devextreme-angular

I am using [devextreme-diagram](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDiagram/) component v22.1.7. It supports custom commands [dxi-command](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDiagram/Configuration/#onCustomCommand). Based on permissions, I need to toggle the visibility of these commands, however the dxi-command itself doesn't provide any supporting property like `visible` or `visibility`. Is there any other way to toggle the visibility of these custom commands?